# como itinerar en colecciones de firebase en nativescript y angular

Tags: angular, firebase, nativescript

Hola alguien me podria ayudar, estoy trabajando con angular y nativescript, estoy utilizano el plugin de firebase, quiero traer datos de las colecciones de firebase a un html, pero viendo la documentacion oficial del plugin que he utilizado, lo unico que he logrado es que estacoleccion se imprima en consola, pero no logro itinerar sobre los datos de esta coleccion https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/FIRESTORE.md esta es la documentacion del plugin, y asi tengo el codigo
AIIUDAAA!! xD[image: 1]

Comment: Podrias pegar el codigo en la pregunta en vez de la foto ? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a cada campo, dentro de tu forEach hace lo siguiente

```
forEach(doc => {
 ...
 const descripcion = doc.data().descripcion;
 const precio = doc.data().precio;
 const oferta = doc.data().titulo;
 const portada = doc.data().portada;

}
```

Comment: dale muchaas gracias...

Comment: Si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta saludos